# Reading RTF directly to a TextView on Android

Tags: c#, java, android, html, rtf

I have a RTF file saved in a database column, i need to read that text and display it with style into a TextView on the Android.

From what i have searched, i didn't find how to read RTF directly on the android.

What i have tried are:

1. Searching for something to convert RTF to HTML (on the web service (C#) and on the Android) (I haven't found a suitable solution, found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) but i didn't know how to use it... too many classes and i didn't know how to deal with it, i will try again until someone replies here
2. Displayed the Text in plain text. (looks very very ugly)

Thanks for Reading, Please try to help

Comment: Would a two stage conversion: RTF -> Text-> HTML work?

Comment: @rossum how will i get the same formatting the RTF did after i make it plain text ?

Comment: If the RTF is in some sort of fixed format, then you can set up an HTML template and feed in the text.  If it is more free-format then you will lose some or all of the formatting.  How complex is the RTF?  There is a basic description of simple RTF at http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod

Comment: @rossum: It's very complex and it's not created with a template :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a class library based on:
[Writing Your Own RTF Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter)
By Jani Giannoudis | 26 Apr 2011

[My project](https://github.com/Shereef/RTF-to-HTML-Converter-Class-Library-DLL) is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/Shereef/RTF-to-HTML-Converter-Class-Library-DLL)

Thanks to the people who read and tried to help.

Comment: i have seen your Github link but i can't find any library for android.

Comment: IIRC I made it in C# and used it at the WCF service

Comment: Just to clarify, does this solution allow you to convert RTF to HTML directly on the Android device?

Comment: Nope, this allows to convert RTF to HTML on .NET