# RTF to HTML (or spannable) in Android

Tags: java, android, html, rtf

I need to convert a rich text format string into a html formatted string or a spannable.

So far I've tried using Apache Tika, but it seems to be very broken and I can't get it to compile from a prebuilt jar or from the source (I suspect it can't be used in Android) and obviously I can't use the standard libraries such as from this example http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136483/Java-How-to-convert-RTF-into-HTML because I can't import the libraries into Android.

This example [Reading RTF directly to a TextView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451191/reading-rtf-directly-to-a-textview-on-android) doesn't seem to be very helpful as I have no idea what C# and WCF service have to do with Android.

Does anyone know of any methods that they know do work?

Comment: I didn't end up finding a library that I could use so I ended up manually stripping the formating from the RTF and leaving the text as it was.

Comment: https://www.scroogexhtml.com/ works well in Android. It is used in the TinyRTFViewer App. (Disclaimer: I am the author)