# How to load .rtf files in webview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

[image]I want to load rtf files with webview using raw folder. Below is my code;

```
 val urlWebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
 readTextFromResource(R.raw.lettemp_369)?.let { urlWebView.loadData(it, "text/rtf", "utf-8") };
```

Below is function;

```
private fun readTextFromResource(resourceID: Int): String? {
val raw: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(resourceID)
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
var i: Int
 try {
i = raw.read()
while (i != -1) {
    stream.write(i)
    i = raw.read()
}
raw.close()
} catch (e: IOException) {
e.printStackTrace()
}
return stream.toString()
}
```

Comment: You asked that before and were told what to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249616/how-to-show-rtf-content-from-raw-file-in-textview-android

Comment: hey @blackapps do you know about how can I set rtf content with simple android textview?

Comment: Webview or textview, you asked that before and were told what to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249616/how-to-show-rtf-content-from-raw-file-in-textview-android

Comment: anything webview or textview. just want to load or print rtf file from raw folder. Because in IOS, it is possible to set rtf content in textview with proper format @blackapps

Comment: can you write your answer with code @blackapps?

Comment: My god.. i did google android rtf library and came upon this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451191/reading-rtf-directly-to-a-textview-on-android

Comment: I couldn't understand how to  use this with android app. Can you guide me @blackapps

Comment: Sorry, never used that library.